# Facebook API getEmail() is null

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, laravel-5

I'm using laravel 5 Socialite and this to create social login https://github.com/laravel/socialite.

When I use this function and when I ran into this `$facebook->getEmail();`
the email I get is null:

```php
public function FacebookInfo()
{
    $facebook = Socialite::driver('facebook')->user();

    $user = new User();

    $user->username = $facebook->getNickname();
    $user->full_name = $facebook->getName();
    $user->avatar = $facebook->getAvatar();
    $user->email = $facebook->getEmail();
    $user->remember_token = $facebook->token;
    $user->level = 1;
    $user->total_post = 0;

    $user->save();

    return redirect()->intended('/');
}
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You have to mention what all fields do you want from Facebook. You can do this by adding a `scope` while redirecting to Facebook for authentication like below,

```
return Socialite::driver('facebook')->scopes(['public_profile','email', 'user_friends'])->redirect();
```

You can learn more about Facebook permissions [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions#reference-email).

**P.S**. Now Facebook also allows mobile number to create an account instead of an email. In that case you will not get an email!!!